# What IP address should I use to connect MySQL with Android Device

Tags: android, mysql, ip

I'm working with Android Studio (I guess in other IDEs same happens) and I'm trying test my app in device android from USB.

The app work with a mysql database in localhost (local server). 
When I emulate the app with AVD works fine with IP 10.0.2.2, but when test this in my device doesn't work with IP 10.0.2.2 or 127.0.0.1 or IP Lan 192.168.1.138.

What IP address should I use?

Comment: connect it with your IP Lan, disable your firewall

Comment: direct android <-> mysql connection? ... what a terrible idea ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than USB you have to connect your android device in wifi network. And both device and your server PC should be in the same network. Then you can use the IP address of your LAN.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I could connect directly using USB.
Another option is upload PHP files and use real data for connection.